# How to use Bootstrap for Sass using Grunt.js and Compass?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I would like to use an offical Sass port of Bootstrap together with task runner Grunt.js and framework Compass but according to manual (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#bootstrap-for-sass) I didn't succeed.

Successfully installed these gems:

```
bootstrap-sass (3.1.0.1, 3.1.0.0)
compass (0.12.2)
sass (3.2.14, 3.2.13, 3.2.12)
```

My Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  compass: {
      options: {
        httpPath: './',
        sassDir: '<%= pkg.css.src %>',
        cssDir: '<%= pkg.css.dest %>',
        imagesDir: '<%= pkg.graphics.cssPath %>'
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          environment: 'development',
          outputStyle: 'expanded',
          force: true
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          environment: 'production',
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          force: true
        }
      }
    },

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass:dev']);
};
```

At the beginning of my custom.scss I have:

```
@import "compass";
@import "boostrap";
```

When I type

> grunt

in command line I get following error:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: boostrap.
   Load paths:
     c:/Users/Radek/WWW/svobodanabytek/src/sass
     C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
     C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
     Compass::SpriteImporter
        on line 2 of c:/Users/Radek/WWW/svobodanabytek/src/sass/custom.scss
```

Without line 2 (*@import "boostrap";*) everything works fine.

What should I do to start using bootstrap-sass gem in Grunt? Install some new Grunt plugin?
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: If you were running Compass by itself, I would point to the fact that you haven't required it in your config.rb.  I know nothing about Grunt or how you would go about specifying the dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this working after having the same problem for so long using [bootstrap-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass).

In your Gruntfile, specify the location of your compass and bootstrap-sass gems in the `includePaths` config variable:

```
options: {
    compass: true,
    includePaths: [
        '/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets',
        '/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/frameworks/compass/stylesheets'
    ],
    ...
}
```

Side note: you can run grunt with the `grunt --verbose` flag to dump extra information helpful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks! Specifying path did the trick! Just for info: when using just SASS (without Compass) the parameter is called `loadPath` - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#loadpath .

Comment: @chr1s Glad it worked! Were you able to get it working with `loadPath` as well? The reason I did not include that in my answer was that it seemed to be completely ignoring that parameter no matter what I put. `includePaths` was the only thing that finally got it working for me

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you spelled bootstrap wrong:

`@import "boostrap";`
 should be `@import "bootstrap";`

Answer (score 1):

You're using grunt for all the beauty it offers, yet you're using the gem of bootstrap.

Grunt uses the npm repo.

For a simple fix, use [bootstrap-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bootstrap-sass)

For a better overall working, merge that above package in with [grunt-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bootstrap) replacing the less files for sass, as well as any other references, then repackage that as your own release. This will then offer the full grunt automation goodies.

Answer (score 0):

In the GruntFile "compass options" you can also add:

```
raw: 'require "bootstrap-sass"'
```

So the options should look something like this:

```
compass: {
    options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/sass',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'require "bootstrap-sass"\nSass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
require: 'bootstrap-sass'
```

in your compass options file, like so:

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: 'src/sass',
    cssDir: 'dist/css',
    environment: 'production',
    require: 'bootstrap-sass'
  }
}
```

This avoids having to hardcode paths in your gruntfile.